# XML Serialization: Object attribute maps to 2 xml elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to serialize an object where one of the attributes maps to 2 xml elements.  I'm creating a program that interfaces with a wifi account management system through its RESTful API.  Here is the object that I need to serialize to create the account:

```
[XmlRoot("record")]
class XmlUser 
{
    [XmlElement("login")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("password")]
    [XmlElement("password_confirmation")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Other attributes...
}
```

Having two `XmlElementAttributes` on one attribute throws an exception, saying I need to add the `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`.  I don't need to deserialize the object. Should I abandon this method, and just use a `XmlWriter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do,

```
[XmlElement("password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[XmlElement("password_confirmation")]
public string PasswordConfirmation{ get { return Password;} set; }
```

Comment: The requires `set {}` (vs `set;`) for the password_confirmation I believe.

Comment: Can I leave out the set on the attributes?

Comment: `get { return passwqord; } set { Password = value; }`